# logout.php page do not redirecting me to member.php page

Tags: php, html

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>register</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> <a href="register.php">register</a> | <a href="login.php">login</a></p>
<h3>registration form</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
emailid: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="login" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('user_registration') or die ("connect select DB");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."'" );
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows==0)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO login(username,password,emailid ) VALUES('$user','$pass','$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "acc succ created";
}
else { echo "failure"; }
}
else { echo "username already exist"; }
}
?>
</body>
</html>

**LOGIN FORM** please go through this login code
```

All things work fine, but the login page doesn't redirect me to the `member.php` page and stays on the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>login</title>

</head><body>
<p><a href="register.php">register</a> | <a href="login.php">login</a></p>
<h3> login form</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="login" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('user_registration') or die ("connect select DB");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername=$row['username'];
$dbpassword=$row['password'];
}
if($user == $row['username'] && $pass == $row['password'])
{
session_start();

$_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;


header("location:member.php");
}
}
else {
echo "invalid username or password";
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>

**MEMBER PAGE**
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess user"])){
header("location:login.php");  

} else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>welcome</title>

</head>
<body>
<h2> welcome <?php $_SESSION['sess_user'];?> ! <a     
href="logout.php">logout</a></h2>
<p>
jfdsjkfhdsf dsf ds fds f sdf ds fds f ds fd sf ds f
</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>

MY LOGOUT PAGE

<?php
session_start();
unset($_Session['sess_user']);
session_destroy();
header("location:login.php");
?>
```

Comment: you have to use `session_Start` and `header` before any outputs "at the first line for example" note that this won't help the redirect

Comment: your $_Session['sess_user']); is wrong in your logout page

Comment: Hello, this is not the right way to ask something on SO. "Help me it's urgent" and CAPS will never motivate anybody to help you. Instead provide us the needed details (and only them) and wait for an answer. Please fix your message. Good luck.

Comment: @AFract You are right. I've edited the text.

Comment: You should bear in mind that your query is open to SQL injection - BIG time. You need to use mysql_real_escape_string (or preferably PDO for your queries) because users can pass in strings which allow them to login without being a valid user.

Comment: right now i don't care about sql injectionn.. please help with code :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't use the `header()` function after output has already been sent (i.e., your HTML). Put your redirect logic before any output.

Comment: can you please explain in code :)

Comment: Hmm... it might be easier to just say that you can't user `header()` after `?>` or `echo` or `var_dump` or `print` or `print_r` or anything else that sends output.

Answer (score 0):

Please write `<?php ob_start();?>` at the top of the page. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

> MY LOGOUT PAGE

```
header("location:member.php")
```

instead of

```
header("location:login.php")
```